# Specifying url in rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

i am totally new to rails programming...  i used the request.path to get the current url and display it in all my views by specifying it in applications.html.erb. It is returning the entire path and i want to display it as a link... so i use 
**link_to** to specify it as url..now here is what i want to do.. the url returned will be in the format path1/path2/path3.....  i want to display it as path1>path2>path3 and as a link such that when the user clicks path1, it should take him to path 1 and so on...

this is the code i gave in html.erb file

but i get an error that says undefined method.... what should i do to accomplish that??

Comment: Did you forget to put the code in?

Comment: The code would be useful to help you

Comment: Why was this up-voted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do like this:

```
 <% path = request.path %>
 <% links = path.split('/') %>
 <% ll="/" %>
 <% links.each do |l| %>
   <% ll += (l+'/') %>
   <%= link_to l,ll %> &gt;
 <% end %>
```

Comment: thanks a lot..this did it... i guess i messed it up while typing code..i didnt know that every line must have <%= %>

Answer (score 2):

You could split the request.path on `/` and then build up the various links, but that could get really cluttered for deeply nested paths. I think a better approach would be to use something like [breadcrumbs_on_rails](https://github.com/weppos/breadcrumbs_on_rails) and declare your breadcrumbs explicitly and render them in a partial or helper method. I think you could also use some Rails filter magic to have action names breadcrumbed automatically, but making the breadcrumbs explicit forces you to think about your site and your users more than programmatically vomiting out a string of links of unknown length.

Comment: installing now bro...will try tis out as well..thanks a lot for sparing ur valuable time to answer my question